# jQuery .each() failed to get value of multiple lines of input value

Tags: jquery

I have this html code generated by PHP :

```
for ($i; $i<$max; $i++) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity" value="'.$sc_quantity.'" min="1" max="10" maxlength="2" size="2" disabled="disable">'    
}
```

and I need to get the value of each `.quantity` class using jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".quantity").each(function(){
        var current_qty = $(this).val();
        alert (current_qty);
    }
});
```

but I can not alert it. means, my selection of `.quantity` is incorrect. how to use `each()` method properly in this case? thank you

Comment: You forgot the closing );

Comment: you're right. it works now. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
$('.quantity').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/85q8w9t1/

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax works fine by adding `);` to your `each` Realized this after  **SachinGutte** pointed it out in comments.

```
$(".quantity").each(function(){
    var current_qty = $(this).val();
    alert (current_qty);
});  // note here you had missed the closing
```

This is one way of doing it by using `$.each('selector',handlerFunction)`

```
$.each(".quantity",function(){
    var current_qty = $(this).val();
    alert (current_qty);
});
```

yet another way is by using the parameters in the callback of the function.

```
$(".quantity").each(function(index, element){
    var current_qty = $(element).val();
    alert (current_qty);
});
```

Note the `function(index, element)` changed in the code..

Comment: You forgot the closing `);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the element parameter to your $.each call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".quantity").each(function(i,el){
        var current_qty = $(el).val();
        alert (current_qty);
    });
});
```